# Proving inequality $3^{n^2} > (n!)^4$

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove that $3^{n^2} > (n!)^4$ for all positive integers $n$.

I tried to use induction on this problem but failed to do so. I instead tried to prove $3^{2n+1}>(n+1)^4$, but couldn't come up with the solution.

Comment: do you mean $4\sum\limits_{k=1}^nlog(k)$?

Comment: You're right, sorry !

Comment: No problem at all ;)

But why did you delete your comment?

Comment: I couldn't modify it anymore. I'd better rewrite it : by taking the logarithm,

$$ \Big( \, 3^{n^2} > (n!)^{4} \, \Big) \; \Leftrightarrow \; \Big( \, \log(3) n^{2} > 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log(k) \, \Big) $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The induction-step should be pretty easy:

- Assume $\displaystyle3^{n^2}>(n!)^4$
- Prove $\displaystyle3^{(n+1)^2}>(n+1)!^4$:

  - $\displaystyle3^{(n+1)^2}=3^{n^2+2n+1}$
  - $\displaystyle3^{n^2+2n+1}=3^{n^2}3^{2n+1}$
  - $\displaystyle3^{n^2}3^{2n+1}>(n!)^43^{2n+1}$
  - $\displaystyle(n!)^43^{2n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!^4}{(n+1)^4}3^{2n+1}$
  - $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)!^4}{(n+1)^4}3^{2n+1}=(n+1)!^4\frac{3^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^4}$

So all you have left to prove by induction is $3^{2n+1}>(n+1)^4$:

- Assume $\displaystyle3^{2n+1}>(n+1)^4$
- Prove $\displaystyle3^{2(n+1)+1}>(n+2)^4$:

  - $\displaystyle3^{2(n+1)+1}=3^{2n+3}$
  - $\displaystyle3^{2n+3}=3^{2n+1}3^2$
  - $\displaystyle3^{2n+1}3^2>(n+1)^43^2$
  - $\displaystyle(n+1)^43^2=9(n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1)$
  - $\displaystyle9(n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1)=9n^4+36n^3+54n^2+36n+9$
  - $\displaystyle9n^4+36n^3+54n^2+36n+9>n^4+8n^3+24n^2+32n+16$
  - $\displaystyle n^4+8n^3+24n^2+32n+16=(n+2)^4$

Comment: I already came up with this, but couldn't prove $3^{2n+1}>(n+1)^4$. I'm just a beginner, sorry.

Comment: @Gary: OK, I added a prove-by-induction for that too...

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Comment: @Gary: You're welcome :) ... Don't forget to add the initial test (with $n=1$) in your formal answer...

Comment: @Gary, to be honest, you should also prove the statement made in the line just before the last line... but this one should be really easy (show that $8n^4+28n^3+30n^2+4n>7$, or again - prove by induction).

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, $n^n > n!$ for $n>1$ and so $n^{4n} > (n!)^4$. Therefore, we only need to prove that $3^{n^2} \ge n^{4n}$, or equivalently, $3^n \ge n^4$. This is true for $n \ge 8$. For $n <8$, we just verify explicitly that $3^{n^2} > (n!)^4$.